# Installing Old PHP Version (5.3.1) on Ubuntu 16.04 Using PHPBrew

Tags: 16.04, php

I hope someone can help me here. I have spent quite a time to figure this out but.. no luck yet. I am very beginner for Ubuntu/Linux.
So I found instruction for phpbrew somewhere and successfully installed it, but I can't install old php version.
To install old php, I used as $ phpbrew install 5.3.1 +default
And I get errors below.
Even if I search those errors on Google, I could not find any solutions.
Could anyone give me some tips how I can install old php version?
I have a project that targets the php version so I really need to install on my local machine to develop some application.

the error I got:

```
===> Checking patches...
Checking patch for php5.3.29 multi-sapi patch.
Checking patch for php5.3.x on 64bit machine when intl is enabled.
3 changes patched.
Checking patch for openssl dso linking patch
===> Building...
Error: Make failed:
The last 5 lines in the log file:
ext/intl/grapheme/grapheme_string.o:(.rodata+0x8): undefined reference to `grapheme_extract_bytecount_iter'

ext/intl/grapheme/grapheme_string.o:(.rodata+0x10): undefined reference to `grapheme_extract_charcount_iter'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Makefile:244: recipe for target 'sapi/cgi/php-cgi' failed

make: *** [sapi/cgi/php-cgi] Error 1

Please checkout the build log file for more details:
     tail /home/buntu/.phpbrew/build/php-5.3.1/build.log

===== build.log details below (/home/buntu/.phpbrew/build/php-5.3.1/build.log)
/home/buntu/.phpbrew/build/php-5.3.1/ext/openssl/openssl.c:917: undefined reference to `EVP_md2'
ext/openssl/xp_ssl.o: In function `php_openssl_setup_crypto':
/home/buntu/.phpbrew/build/php-5.3.1/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:324: undefined reference to `SSLv2_client_method'
/home/buntu/.phpbrew/build/php-5.3.1/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:344: undefined reference to `SSLv2_server_method'
ext/intl/grapheme/grapheme_string.o:(.rodata+0x0): undefined reference to `grapheme_extract_count_iter'
ext/intl/grapheme/grapheme_string.o:(.rodata+0x8): undefined reference to `grapheme_extract_bytecount_iter'
ext/intl/grapheme/grapheme_string.o:(.rodata+0x10): undefined reference to `grapheme_extract_charcount_iter'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:244: recipe for target 'sapi/cgi/php-cgi' failed
make: *** [sapi/cgi/php-cgi] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install PHP as a part of XAMPP package. The XAMPP contains Apache, PHP, MySQL and  Perl. [The XAMPP 1.7.7](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/1.7.7/) is the most updated XAMPP with PHP version 5.3.

You can find more information on [Stackoverflow](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/1.7.7/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need openssl just omit it from build

```
phpbrew install 5.3.1 +default-openssl
```